# jQuery validation stops when an input field display is changed to block from none

Tags: jquery, validation, input, onclick, hidden-field

I have a form with following elements

```
<div class="form-group form-register-group">
    <label for=""></label>
    <div class="right-box w-100">
        <input type="number" class="otp_input form-control d-none" style="width: 130px;" name="email_otp" id="email_otp" placeholder="Email OTP" value="{{@$email_otp}}"/>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group form-register-group">
    <label for=""></label>
    <div class="right-box w-100">
        <button id="email_otp_btn" class="get_otp_btn btn btn-primary">Get OTP on Email</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

And below is the JS code which gets executed when I click the OTP button

```
$('.get_otp_btn').on('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#email_otp_btn').removeClass('block').addClass('d-none');
    $('#email_otp').removeClass('d-none');
});
```

Basic validation like *required* works on the form when I click the submit button.
But as soon as I click the OTP button, and then click the submit button of the form, the form gets submitted and ignores the validations of other fields.

Debugging shows that `$('#email_otp').removeClass('d-none');` was the culprit, commenting this line made my validation work again. How to hide/display an input field without screwing up the validations?

Comment: can you make your code runnable to show that behaviour ?

Answer (score 0):

`e.preventDefault();` prevent submitting a form. just remove it.